Does zero derivative on a non-open connected set imply function is constant
The following is well-known:
Theorem A: If $E$ is an open, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then any function $f\colon E\to\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable everywhere on $E$ with $f'=0$ must be constant.
However, even if $E$ is not open, one can still define the derivative at any point $x_0\in E$ which is not isolated, namely $f'(x_0)$ is the unique linear map $A\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that the error
$$\|f(x)-f(x_0)-A(x-x_0)\|=o(\|x-x_0\|),$$
provided it exists. (For instance, $E$ could be the Cantor set.)
This question is about whether both openness and connectedness of $E$ are needed in Theorem A.
Clearly connectedness is needed. However, it seems to me that the openness assumption is mostly there as a convenient way to

Ensure that $E$ is path-connected;

Ensure that $E$ is locally convex,


either of which would allow one to reduce the problem further. However, I'm uncertain if connectedness by itself is sufficient. More precisely:
Question: Suppose $E$ is connected with no isolated points. Then without assuming that $E$ is open, does Theorem $A$ still hold? If not, would it suffice to assume that $E$ is path-connected?
Remark: I cannot think of any simple case (e.g. $E$ is a rectangle or a piecewise smooth curve or the topologist's sine curve) where it would be false. But perhaps there are more subtle geometries where a counter-example exists?

I suspect that some crazy-looking path e.g. Osgood curves might lead to a counterexample. (I'm not certain, it's just an idea.) By the way, if you don't get a satisfactory answer in 24 hours, you can consider posting on Math Overflow - in case it's a professor-level question

For a non-isolated point there may be a linear $A$ as you write, but in general it will not be unique. This is what openness assures.

@PaulFrost I see, that makes sense. I wonder, then, if we can do without the openness condition under the additional assumption that the derivative is unique.

Why do you bring up isolated points?  If $\vert E\vert \geq 2$ has an isolated point $p$ then I define continuous $g:E\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ where $g(p)=0$ and $g$ sends everything else to $1$; conclude $E$ is not connected.

I finally got an answer, see edit

Further to my comment,
If there is a continuous injective $f:S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$  such that $\frac{|f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(y)|}{d(x,y)}\to0$ uniformly as $d(x,y)\to0$, then $f^{-1}:\text{Image}(f)\to S^{1}$ will be the counterexample you want.
EDIT:
The answer to my question on Overflow provides such a function.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483651/jordan-plane-curve-such-that-fracdgx-gydx-y-to0
Note that the Koch snowflake has no tangent line at any point according to Wikipedia, and therefore the derivative would be uniquely defined.

Interesting example! It's not quite clear to me that the derivative is uniquely 0, but I can believe it given the shape of the snowflake. Thanks for asking on MO too.

The range of $f^{-1}$ is not $\mathbb R$ as required in the question. But certainly one of the two coordinate functions will do.

This is not an answer, but an extended comment.
In your question you defined a function $f : E \to \mathbb R$ to be differentiable at a non-isolated point $x_0 \in E$ if there exists a linear $A: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$\|f(x)-f(x_0)-A(x-x_0)\|=o(\|x-x_0\|) . \tag{1}$$
Note that differentiability at $x_0$ implies continuity at $x_0$.
The problem is that $A$ is in general not unique. As an example take $E = \mathbb R \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb R^2$ and the zero function $f(x) = 0$. Then you take any linear $A$ of the form $A(x_1,x_2) = rx_2$.
Thus you cannot call $A$ the derivative - but if you want a derivative.
You may only consider the case that $A$ is unique, and there are certainly conditions on $E$ weaker than "$E$ open" assuring this. For example, each product of intervals $E = J_1 \times \ldots \times J_n$ has this property.
Anyway, you can modify your question (for connected $E$) as follows:

If $f$ is differentiable having a zero-derivative at all $x_0 \in E$, is $f$ constant?

In other words

If $$\|f(x)-f(x_0))\|=o(\|x-x_0\|) \text{ for all } x_0 \in E , \tag{2}$$ is $f$ constant?

Here are some positive results.

Let $u : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ be a differentiable path such that $u([0,1]) \subset E$. Then $v = f \circ u : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable with $v' = 0$.

Proof. You can copy the proof of the multivariable chain rule.

If $E$ is "piecewise differentiably path connected" (which means that for any two $x,y \in E$ there exist (1) a finite sequence of points $x_0,\ldots, x_k \in E$ such that $x = x_0$ and $y = x_k$ and (2) differentiable paths  $u_i : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ such that $u_i([0,1]) \subset E$), then $f$ is constant.
Note that connected open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are piecewise differentiably path connected. This reproduces the theorem in your question.

Proof. This follows from 1.
Based on the above idea we can define the concept of "piecewise differentiable path components" of $E$.  Clearly, $f$ is constant on each piecewise differentiable path component of $E$. By continuity $f$ is even constant on the closure of each piecewise differentiable path component of $E$ (closure is taken in the space $E$).

If there exist countably many piecewise differentiable path components $E_i$ of $E$ such that that $\bigcup \overline{E_i} = E$, then $f$ is constant.
Note that the proof will show that it is sufficient to require that $f$ is continuous and all $f\mid_{E_i}$ are differentiable with a zero-derivative.

Proof. Since $f$ is continuous, the image $f(E)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb R$, thus an interval (possibly unbounded) or a singleton. We have
$$f(E) = f\left(\bigcup_i \overline{E_i}\right) =\bigcup_i f\left(\overline{E_i}\right) .$$
But each $f\left(\overline{E_i}\right)$ is a singleton, thus $f(E)$ is countable. A countable set cannot be an interval, thus $f(E)$ must be a singleton.

If there exist finitely many piecewise differentiable path components $E_i$ of $E$ whose union is dense in $E$, then $f$ is constant.
Again it is sufficient to require that $f$ is continuous and all $f\mid_{E_i}$ are differentiable with a zero-derivative.

Proof. For finite unions $\overline{\bigcup_i E_i} = \bigcup_i \overline{E_i}$.
